# Can't run Android Demo - No Resource Identifier Found

Tags: android

I am trying to run the AnimationsDemo from the android developers website:

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

But I can't manage to compile it. I keep getting an error with the R.java file as it is not being generated. Hence, in all the Activity classes I get an error saying "R cannot be resolved into a variable).

I also have errors in the manifest file saying:

> "error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'parentActivityName' in package 
>    'android'"

It seems like it cannot find the any of the activity classes found in R.Layout. I did NOT import the "android.R" file so I know that's not the issue. I haven't really touched the code, so I can't figure out why it's complaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'parentActivityName' in package 'android'

This usually means that your build target (e.g., Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse) is set too low. Try raising it to a higher API level -- 14 or higher should work. You may need to download additional API levels through the SDK Manager depending upon what you have installed.

Comment: Thank you! that was it! Stuff like that can take soo long to debug :)

Comment: @fouadalnoor: It should be better documented, which is why I filed an issue about it: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59881

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the xml layout file and the activity class. Also share common features like the bg, font, and scheme. Etc.